# How to feed kernel messages as KDE notification system

Tags: kernel, kde, notification

Is there a way to get the kernel messages into the KDE notification system?

I want to see a GUI notification when my kernel detected a problem.

Comment: Gold Star question. My 10 cents python (choose your fave) script to grep the kernel message log every x seconds and pipe the results to notify from x second to y second with possibly a filter to only pipe messages containing error, trouble ahead, crash and burn etc.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put this into your autostart:

`sh -c 'tail -n 1 -f /var/log/syslog | while read LINE; do notify-send "$LINE";done'`

or into a bash script watch_syslog.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
tail -n 1 -f /var/log/syslog | while read LINE; do notify-send "$LINE";done
```

at least this works under GNOME... You only need to substitute the appropriate tool for KDE instead of notify-send:

```
tail -n 1 -f /var/log/syslog | while read LINE; do kdialog --passivepopup "$LINE" 3;done
```

Comment: notify-send also works on KDE. Thx